# selenium: web form submitting

Tags: forms, selenium, selenium-rc

I have this task as a homework for interview - to test the webpage of popular site. Got a pop up form with some text in the fields. The task is to check is there are fields has been changed. 
The page constructed that way, doesent matter if the data changed, popup window just closed with no additional text about it. I have no idea how to deal with it. Is there any commands in selenium checking, if the form has been sent?

## add1

This is a PopUp changing profile window. It is shown below with my translations as the red font. 
It is obvious, when this window opens, some values are already in the textfields (that is ur name/surname that u've entered before).
When u press the save button, this page checks if the data been changed since this window been opened (did u really changed anything). 
The html code of "save" button has been shown on the pic2. U can see javaScript listener on the save button. There are somewhere must be a JS code, that checks if the data been changed and sends the form, and canceling the form sending, if there's no changing.

[image: pic1]
[image]
My Goal is to check using selenium, if the form has been sent.

Comment: Are you want to check the `text field, buttons, etc...` are present in the PopUp? Am i right?

Comment: Is there any result page after sending the form?

Comment: @Manigandan no, they are exist there. I guess there's a JavaScript listener on submit button, that checks data and cancel form sending. Is it possible for JS?

Comment: @Pavel Janicek they're not any

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. Please, be a little more specific, show us some example HTML code or a screenshot of what you're trying to do. "The task is to check is there are fields has been changed." -> changed since when? Since the open of the popup? Since last time? Are you trying to validate the form, or are you trying to send the form? Are you trying to check whether it has really been sent?

Comment: @Slanec ..fields has been changed since the open of the popup. Trying to check whether it has really been sent. I've added more information to my post.

Comment: Ok, so with Selenium you want to test two cases: 1. form values are mutated and therefor the form should be submitted, 2. form values remain unchanged, therefor the form should not be submitted. So what you need to know is what happens to the website in those two cases. If you know, then you can use Selenium to automatically check. For instance, if submitted, an alert-box will be shown, else only the popup will be closed. In Selenium you can verify both those examples. We need more info to give you a specific answer though...